# Building C file in Sublime Text 3 and using fork();

Tags: c, sublimetext3

(running on a mac) My C.sublime-build file looks like this:

```
{
"cmd" : ["gcc -Wall -g $file_name -o ${file_base_name} && ./${file_base_name}"],
"selector" : "source.c",
"shell": true,
"working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

and I have a simple program with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    printf("hi\n");
    fork();
    printf("bye\n");

    return 0;
}
```

and sublime will execute it and give me

```
hi
bye
hi
bye
```

while executing from the shell gives me the correct result,

```
hi
bye
bye
```

why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ISO C:

> Standard input and standard output are fully buffered, unless they
>   refer to a terminal device, in which case, they are line buffered.

When you're using ST3, it does not refer to a terminal device so it is fully buffered. It means `hi\n` and `bye\n` will be stored in buffer zone and `fork()`will copy them to child process. Then both of them will be output twice.

When you're using the shell, you're using a terminal device and it is line buffered. During thr execution, `hi\n` will be output firstly and buffer zone is flushed due to the `\n`. Then `bye\n` is send to buffer zone and will be output twice.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that when sublime executes it that stdout, for whatever reason, is not using line buffered output but fully buffered output instead.  So, when you fork() the child, the "hi\n" still resides on the child's FILE too.  The output of both is only flushed when the programs exit and they both print the same output.